Spring boot angular application NOT updating to browser
I am working on a school project and I am running into the issue of where my project is not updating to the browser.
I've deleted everything on the app.component.html, and the deleted information still shows on the browser.
Any advice?
I've cleared my cache from chrome, used incognito, did clean mvn install, deleted node_modules & package.json and reinstalled them, and still nothing is updated.

Are you talking about where you published the website? Cause if you delete files it should not be able to be shown, but with angular you build the the code before deploy, typically the code would be in a /dist folder. But it depends on how its been setup.
